# Why is $B_n$ in the domain of $H$ on a Hilbert Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $H:D(H)\subset \mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator.
Let $B_n:= in(H+in)^{-1}$.

For $\phi\in\mathcal{H}$ it is given in my notes that $B_n\phi\in D(H)$, where $D(H)$ is the domain of $H$. Why is this? I lack the background in Functional Analysis to make the immediate connection.

Comment: It's really just the trivial fact that the inverse of a map $F$, if it exists, maps the range of $F$ into the **domain** of $F$.  Here $F = H+in$ and its domain is the same as that of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the operator is self-adjoint its spectrum is contained in the real line, this means that $-in$ is not in its spectrum. By definition this means that there is a bounded operator $R(H, -in)$ (formally $R(H,-in) = (H+in)^{-1}$) such that its range is in $D(H)$ that satisfies
$$(H + in)R(H, -in) = Id\quad R(H,-in)(H + in) \subseteq Id,$$
here the inclusion means that this operator defined a priori in $D(H)$ is a restriction o the identity.